# Can I create a checkin with a type of checkin from a webpage with Foursquare API

Tags: api, foursquare, checkin

I have a `.NET` web application and I want to check users into `FourSquare` when they log into my website. Using the 4Square API I can authorize without problem but depending on the params I pass to in the check in call it returns with a checkin type of either "Shout" or "Venueless". I have not been able to create a check-in with a type of "CheckIn".

The problem is that the types of 'Shout" or "Venueless" are not being counted as checkins at the venue place I created. From what I've been reading I'm wondering if this is possible. It works from FourSqaures [web app](https://foursquare.com/mobile/)

I'm posting to [this address](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add) and passing the users `auth token`, the `venueId`, `broadcast=public` and the shout text. I have also tried adding the latitude and longitude from my venue item (I know this is frowned upon).

I always get back a type of 'Shout" unless I include the venue param and then I get back a type of 'Venueless".

```
My VenueID = 4eeb40877beb28478d78928a
Versioning = 20111201
```

Any help/ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Venues are supposed to be tied to physical locations. Do you have any idea if users logging into your site are actually at a location corresponding to your venue?

Comment: We have a couple of corporate locations that users would be physically logging in from and would like to capture it as a single location.

Comment: That's not really a use case foursquare is designed for capturing. Check-ins and venues are about physical locations, so aggregating disparate locations doesn't really map over well

Comment: I'll create a venue for each location that way each user will phyically be in each location. I can then combine their history in my app. As for the check-in type problem the issue was that I passed the "venueId" param as "venueid" (no capital I) in my app.  Thankks for your input akdotcom......

Answer (score 0):

Each location should have a venue created in Foursquare regardless. Make sure that you can provide an accurate lat/long location (perhaps by their browser's location services) before posting the check-in/add.

*Summarizing the commented conversation above so that this question no longer appears as unanswered on SO*